# Kernel of linear representation of Baumslag-Solitar group

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $BS(m,n)$ be the Baumslag-Solitar group defined by $B(m,n) =  < a,b ~|~ b a^m b^{-1} = a^n > $, $mn \neq 0$. There is a linear representation of $BS(m,n)$ by mapping $a$ to the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 1&1 \cr 0&1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $b$ to the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{n}{m}&0 \cr 0&1\end{matrix}\right)$. Denote this representation homomorphism as $f$, assume $|m| \neq |n|$, my main question is:

> What is the kernel of $f$ ?

Some observations

(1) Commutator of the form $ [a, a^b], [a,a^{b^2} ], [a,a^{b^3}] \ldots$, are in the kernel. Do these elements generate the Kernel of $f$? Do they form an infinite generated  free group? .

(2) If $|m| \ne |n|$ and either $|m| = 1$ or $|n| = 1$ then $f$ is known to be injective.

Comment: The answer is _No_, if you take $|n|=1=|m|$.

Comment: Hi, Anton Klyachko. Your answer is contained in my second observation.


Comment: If $|m|=|n|=1$, then $f$ is _not_ injective and the kernel is _not_
generated by the commutators (1). 

Comment: Anton, you are right. I will edit the question to rule out those cases.

Comment: Actually, if $|m|=|n|$, then $f$ is not njective and its kernel is not generated by commutators (1). 

Comment: I will rule out those cases also. Thank you, Anton

Comment: If you are wondering whether one can use this map to prove the Farrell-Jones conjecture for the remaining Baumslag Solitar groups: Yes this works. Preimages of cyclic subgroups not contained in  $\mathbb{Z}[1/mn]$ are free and the preimage of this group arises as a tree of groups which are either infinite cyclic or trivial. Hence we can use Lemma 2.4 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.6378.pdf to deduce the result.

Comment: Currently Giovanni Gandini, Sebastian Meinert and I are trying to make the argument as general as possible, the current hope it to get fundamental groups of graphs of abelian groups (including generalized Baumslag Solitar groups for example).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The kernel $K$ is a free group of infinite rank.

To see that it is a free group, take the action of $BS(m,n)$ on the Bass-Serre tree $T$ of the usual graph of groups presentation for the usual HNN decomposition $Z*_Z$, where one of the $Z \mapsto Z$ edge-to-vertex homomorphisms is multiplication by $m$ and the other is multiplication by $n$. Each vertex stabilizer of $BS(m,n)$ is conjugate to the $\langle a \rangle$ subgroup, whose intersection with $K$ is trivial. So, all vertex stabilizers of the action of $K$ on $T$ are trivial, implying that all edge stabilizers are trivial. $K$ therefore acts properly discontinuously on the tree $T$.

One can show that the rank is infinite by exhibiting arbitrarily long simple closed edge paths in the quotient graph $T/K$, although maybe there is a slicker way.

Comment: Yes, but how does it actually sit in the mother group?

Comment:   @Igor: Would a good answer to your followup question be a listing of a free basis in terms of a,b? If so, that could be worked out by going back and forth between the action of BS(m,n) on $\mathbb{H}^2$ and the action on T. 

Comment: @ Lee, I will try to work it out by myself using your method. If I could answer all the question I asked, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a complete answer, but here is an observation that I hope is helpful.

Since linear groups are residually finite, the kernel clearly contains the finite residuum, ie the intersection of all the finite-index subgroups. By Theorem 4.1 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3805) by Jack Button *and m and n are coprime*, the finite residuum is equal to the second derived subgroup.

(Thanks to Yves Cornulier for pointing out the missing hypothesis.)

Comment: if $m,n$ are not coprime, I think there are non-metabelian finite quotients. (blast, why don't we have a word to mean the "residuallyfinitization"...)

Comment: Sorry, yes of course you're right.  If m and n are not coprime then in fact B(m,n) is large, ie has a finite-index subgroup that surjects a non-abelian free group.  My answer holds in the coprime case.

Comment: (Yves, re: the word, we do; it's the profinite completion!  It's just in the wrong category.) 

Comment: No, I mean the quotient by the intersection of the finite index subgroup. It's distinct from profinite completion.

Comment: Yves - I know!  But it's morally the same thing as the profinite completion - just in a different category.  Just my bad joke.

Comment: Hi, HW. Can you explain a little bit more about when B(m,n) are not coprime then it has a finite index subgroup that surjects a non-abelian free group.

Comment: Xiaolei Wu, see, for instance, the third paragraph of section 5 of my paper with Cameron Gordon: 'On surface subgroups of doubles of free groups'. http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3693 